# how to redirect $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"] url?

Tags: php

in my project i am changing my folder name for example folder mobile had old name category. so,now i want is if any user enter category in url it should redirect to mobile folder. i tried this in my init.php(not server) file but not any success.

```
if (strpos($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"], "/category/")) {
    $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]="/mobile/";
}
```

or

```
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"], "/category/") {
    $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]="/mobile/";
}
```

i want every request in url with category should redirect to mobile.

Comment: You should do this at the server level. Look into `.htaccess` or `web.config` and URL redirects, depends on server being used..

Comment: how to do it in .htaccess?

Comment: There are many examples out there. Take a look here, http://www.internetmarketingninjas.com/blog/search-engine-optimization/301-redirects/.

Comment: ok. it's done but now problem is. if my url is http://www.example.com/profile/?pr=ravi_matirial_amd. i want to redirect at http://www.example.com/profile/?pr=ravi.matirial.amd. this is not for only one url. i want it for many. in short i want to change _(underscore) to .(dot) in my url. any suggestion?